# Determining whats the Induced Metric

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

I have the normed space $({\rm Lip}([0,1]), \|\cdot\|)$, where ${\rm Lip}([0,1])$ is all Lipschitz functions from $[0,1]$ to $\Bbb R$, and

$$\|f\|=|f(0)|+\sup_{0\le x,y\le 1}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|}$$ where $x$ doesn't equal $y$, and I want to show that $({\rm Lip}([0,1]), d)$ is complete as I want to show that the normed space is a Banach Space.

My question is, what is the induced metric from this normed space?  It's probably a really simple question but I am confused about it.  Is it simply

$$d(f,g)=\sup_{0\le t\le 1}|f(t)-g(t)|?$$

If its not this could someone help me out?  Or verify this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The induced metric of any normed linear space is always

$$d(f,g) = \|f - g\|.$$

In your case, that would be

$$d(f,g) = \|f - g\| = |f(0) - g(0)| + \sup_{0 \leq x,y \leq 1} \frac{|f(x) - g(x) - (f(y) - g(y))|}{|x - y|}.$$

Comment: Ahhhhh this clears up everything about my confusion on induced metrics!  Thanks!